# Custom bound skype call / Voice Message using some audio files/ text as source to a phone number from my skype account in my c# application

Tags: c#, skype, phone-call, ivr

I need a custom bound skype call / Voice Message using some audio files/ text as source 
to a phone number from my skype account in my c# application.
I need to got the respond from the receiver by pressing key 1 or 0 like that.
Is it possible through skype using SKYPE4COM ? .